# Python: selenium: Selecting Item in Dropdown list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

For the life of me I cant figure this out. Until this morning I had a working program but firefox updated which caused me to have to update to the geckodrive and to the latest selenium.
For the life of me I cant get access to dropdown menus.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


 driver = webdriver.Firefox()


 driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")

 dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='searchLanguage']")

 select = Select(dropdown)
 select.select_by_value("de")
```

Comment: Any error you facing ?

Comment: nope no errors just goes through the code, opens the browser and goes to the address but thats it.

Comment: I did fix it though Im not sure way but with firefox 48 i had it didnt work.  I checked for another update which updated me 50 and now it works just like expected.

Comment: is it opening the site ?

Comment: With firefox 48 It will open the site but didnt interact with the drop down but like I said I got no errors.  Once I updated firefox for the second time yesterday the code worked just like it was supposed to.